# How to serialize C++ objects containing ROS messages

Tags: ros, serialization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I have the following class I'd like to serialize:

```
class Foo
{  int x;
   std::vector<double> bars;
   moveit_msgs::RobotState _startState;
}
```

in the absence of any ROS/MoveIt components, I am able to serialize out/in using the Boost serialization library. I resume that if all I had was the moveit message type then I could use the move_it serialization described on  MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes (assuming moveit_msgs are serializable by ROS?). But when I have a class containing both then I am not sure what to do. How do I go about serializing it now? I am using ROS Groovy

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173959/how-to-serialize-c++-objects-containing-ros-messages/) by [sned](https://answers.ros.org/users/18910/sned/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS you cannot serialize and send arbitrary datatypes, you need to use ROS message datatypes. Some libraries provide custom mappings from native datatypes to ROS message-serialized formats. But you need a target ROS message format.

More on messages here: http://wiki.ros.org/Messages

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you're using boost::serialization

ROS message don't implement boost::serialization::Serializable, so you'll need to implement a serialize() function as described here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html

ROS already has serializers for messages, so you may be able to use those to implement the boost serialization. I'm not aware of much documentation about how to call the ROS serializers in C++. the best place to start is probably the source: https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/blob/indigo-devel/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1